# How to make a centered label under the text in bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap navbar like follows

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/br/nd"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/brand/all/show">link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/trans_t"><i class="fa fa-random"></i>link3</a><span class="label label-info">1</span></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Current scenerio looks like follows

[image]

Is it possible the 1 bubble is directly under the text buy sell online...Currently its even going out of the navbar

Comment: Where is the text "buy sell online" in your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that it didn't interfere with the flow, on small viewports the element is position absolute, that's because the link in the navbar is a block and I didn't want to mess with it. On larger viewports, it centers below the text. Needs a wrapper to do this.

### Demo: http://jsbin.com/gozumi/1/

[image]

### HTML

```
    <header class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default" id="top" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="../" class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/br/nd"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/brand/all/show">link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/trans_t"><i class="fa fa-random"></i> Some Words Go Here</a><span class="label-wrap"><span class="label label-info">1</span></span></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

### CSS

```
.navbar-nav .label-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 8px;
    height: 10px;
}
@media (min-width:768px) { 
    .navbar-nav .label-wrap {
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        height:auto;
        position: static;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: -10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's simple!

put your label inside your ancor:

from:

```
<li><a href="/trans_t"><i class="fa fa-random"></i>link3</a><span class="label label-info">1</span></li>
```

to:

```
<li><a href="/trans_t"><i class="fa fa-random"></i>link3 <span class="label label-info">1</span></a></li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cfvbea19/

Comment: did u read it carefully...i said Is it possible the 1 bubble is directly under the text buy sell online